How do I compare the names on two sheets and count upon many parameters?
I have a referral tracking spreadsheet that constantly is getting new names added to it. We have a 3rd party that we reach out to for assistance when needed. I want to track the amount of times we reached out to the 3rd party and completed the process. What is the best way to do this? I have created a sample spreadsheet and will show in photos.
Sheet1 - A list of names and a column saying if the intake was complete or not Sheet1 names



Name
Completion Status




Jarrod
Intake Complete


Thomas
Intake Complete


Victoria
Intake Complete


Debbie
Intake Not Complete



Sheet2 - A list of names that we had to ask for help for. All names that are on Sheet1 may not be on sheet 2. It also has a column for if help was provided Sheet2



Name
Help?




Jarrod
Yes


Thomas
No


Victoria
Yes


Debbie
No



Sheet3 - This is the statistics page where I call a function to count the total number of people on Sheet1 and Sheet2 that have a "Yes" in the help column (Sheet2 column B) and an "Intake Completed" in column B on Sheet1.
Here is the function I'm trying to use and get no results
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,"<>",Sheet2!A:A,"<>",Sheet1!B:B,"Intake Completed",Sheet2!B2:B,"Yes")

The result should be 2 as two people have an intake complete and have received help.

Please specify where names can repeat.

So let's say Sheet1 has a list of 50 names. We only add the name to Sheet2 if we are reaching out for help. Sometimes we reach out for help and get no response. Some people on Sheet1 we complete the process without ever needing to ask for help.

Ok, can names repeat on sheet1 or sheet2?

If the name is on sheet1 and we need help it will be on sheet2. The same name will not be on the same sheet twice.

You can use SUMPRODUCT and ISNUMBER with MATCH to count the names that meet both criteria.COUNTIFS is designed to count cells across multiple ranges that meet multiple criteria, but it doesn't directly compare values across different sheets.
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!B:B="Intake Complete"), --(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!A:A, Sheet2!A:A, 0))), --(Sheet2!B:B="Yes"))


Works perfectly! How can I adjust it to include multiple Sheet1's? As an example we have multiple people with sheets that all add to Sheet2. Would I simply use the same formula and add a + and include the same formula but referencing the other sheet?

Yes, you can combine data from multiple sheets into a single sheet (Sheet2) by using the same formula and adding a + to include references to the other sheets.

I got it working but it seems to not work if the name has a space. Example First Name, Last name. How can I fix this?

It does not matter, because you use column reference instead of title.

A way to do this is by using the IF and AND function and adding another column. For instance, add a new column to sheet 1 called condition.
Use the following formula in the column "condition":
=IF(AND(Sheet1!B2=Sheet2!B2;Sheet1!B2="Intake Complete";Sheet2!B2="Yes");1;0)

Pull the formula down to the last name (Debbie in this case)
And use the function SUM to calculate the count of the cells that match the two conditions.

How can I do this if the name has a space in it? So first name and last name.

Adding a space to the name variable shouldn't change the output of the formula. It is still important that the names are in the same order in the same sheets, because then it can check if the names are available in both sheets.

Unfortunately, that isn't possible. We have 7 different people with their own sheet of names, and all add to the one shared sheet at different times.
